# Problem in getting the output using AGG function for changing the names in the Dictionary of agg()

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to get Average and Sum of `POPESTIMATE2010` and `POPESTIMATE2011` which is in the dataframe. But when i give this Code its just showing the sum of both the Columns separately . But average is not getting displayed . How do i get the average also ? 
The way i want my output is `STNAME, POPESTIMATE2010AVG,POPESTIMATE2011AVG,POPESTIMATE2010sum, POPESTIMATE2011sum`

```
(df.set_index('STNAME').groupby(level=0)['POPESTIMATE2010','POPESTIMATE2011']
    .agg({'POPESTIMATE2010': np.average, 'POPESTIMATE2011': np.average,'POPESTIMATE2010':np.sum,'POPESTIMATE2011':np.sum}))
```

Comment: Problem is in `{'POPESTIMATE2010': np.average, 'POPESTIMATE2011': np.average,'POPESTIMATE2010':np.sum,'POPESTIMATE2011':np.sum}`, `keys` of dict has to be always unique, so need dictionary of lists with unique `keys`

Comment: ooh yes .. exactly.. But how do we modify the code according to the requirement.